# Simulate a mouse-click inside an ArcGIS Online JavaScript Application

Tags: javascript, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, arcgis-online

I have a JavasScript application consuming an ArcGIS Online Web Map.  I want to open a default popup at a specific coordinate.  Is there a way to simulate a mouse-click at that point, or a better alternative?

Answer (score 2):

The [map's default `infoWindow`](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jsapi/map-amd.html#infowindow) should actually be an instance of `esri/dijit/Popup`, so the way to have it behave as if a user has just clicked on a given feature is to call its `setFeatures()` method.

```
var point;
var query = new esri.tasks.Query();
// TODO: set query paramters

var deferred = featureLayer.selectFeatures(query,esri.layers.FeatureLayer.SELECTION_NEW);
deferred.then(function(results) {
  // TODO: set point based on geometry of selected feature(s)
  map.infoWindow.setFeatures(results.features);
  map.infoWindow.show(point);
});
```

See [the feature layer with popup sample](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jssamples/fl_popup.html) and [the `Popup` API page](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jsapi/popup-amd.html#setfeatures) for details.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using the Javascript API you can use the `show` method in the `InfoWindowBase` class to display a popup at a given XY pair. See https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jsapi/infowindowbase-amd.html#show

Comment: Thanks Kevin, but the issue I'm having now is that I wanted the popup to have the format that I configured in ArcGIS Online.  I have not figured out a way to do this through the JavaScript.

Comment: Ah that's getting out of my realm of experience. Have you seen the samples for the JavaScript API that bring in ArcGIS Online maps? If not, that could be a starting point. https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jssamples/ags_editor.html